# vision_opencv can't be found by ROS but it's installed

Tags: ros, opencv, opencv2, vision-opencv, catkin-create-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to make a package using the `catkin_create_pkg` but later it gives me an error for a package I have.

My command was:

```
 catkin_create_pkg opencv_ros sensor_msgs cv_bridge roscpp std_msgs vision_opencv
```

and it says that is was successful, after I run this command:

```
rospack depends1 opencv_ros
```

and I get this error:

> [rospack] Error: package 'opencv_ros'
> depends on non-existent package
> 'vision_opencv' and rosdep claims that
> it is not a system dependency. Check
> the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling
> 'rosdep update'

the problem is that the package exist. If I run the command:

```
roscd vision_opencv
```

it takes me to this location

> /opt/ros/indigo/share/vision_opencv

and the folder of the package is next to all the other packages. The only thing that looked weird is that the folder has only a `package.xml` file in it.

What I want to be able to is use opencv in ROS. Say that I only want to use opencv functions with out moving images form one node to the other (all the loading and processing in one file) what else do I need except vision_opencv package (and making changes in the CMakeList.txt and pagkage.xml) ?
I am using ubuntu 14.04 64bit with ROS indigo. I use the catkin system.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191305/vision_opencv-can%27t-be-found-by-ros-but-it%27s-installed/) by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2014-08-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The essential problem is that `vision_opencv` is a [metapackage](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/package.xml#Metapackages), not a package. A package should never depend, actually, it cannot depend on a metapackage. There is a great discussion about why this is the case [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ros-sig-buildsystem/mn-VCkl2OHk/-9FoB15ixE0J).

In your package, depending on `cv_bridge` should be enough. Note that the [package.xml](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/blob/indigo/cv_bridge/package.xml) in `cv_bridge` adds a bunch of system dependencies (such as `libopencv-dev`).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2014-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on 2014-08-27**:
@jarvisschultz Yes, now I see the problem. Now when I was building some simple code it works fine (by using cv_brinde only) but when I try to put some other code with Surf or Sift (from openCV) it gives me error. Where do I need to look to solve this problem (I mean in what file)?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2014-08-27**:
I'm guessing that your issue is related Surf and Sift moving to a "nonfree" module that doesn't seem to be installed with the `apt-get` packages on 14.04. See [this question/answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/186334/ros-indigo-cv_bridge-opencv-248-source-install/)

**Comment by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on 2014-08-27**:
@jarvisschultz The same code works fine when I run it in "Code::Blocks" and the "nonfree" header is in my openCV folder. Will it make a difference if I build ROS from source instead of installing it the recommended way (according to the tutorials) ?